# Spring Boot Controller WebMvcTest with JWT fails in MockHttpServletRequest.setAttribute

Tags: spring, jwt

Running with Spring Boot v2.3.4.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.9.RELEASE, JWT 0.11.2

Completed successfully before implementing JWT. Am not sure what Attirbute MockHttpServletRequest is looking for?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = AuthorizationController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Slf4j
public class AuthorizationControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @MockBean
    private AuthorizationServiceImpl authorizationService;
    
    @MockBean
    CorsFilter corsFilter;

    @MockBean
    JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @MockBean
    JwtAccessDeniedHandler jwtAccessDeniedHandler;
    
    @MockBean
    JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
    
    @MockBean
    JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    
    @Value("${auth.jwt.client_id}")
    private String clientId;
    
    @Value("${auth.jwt.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    
    @Test
    @DisplayName("When authorization request, then return token")
    public void whenAuthenticate_givenClientValid_thenReturnToken() {
        try {
            RequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/app/auth")
                .headers(buildClientHeaders())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(builder).andReturn();
            int status = result.getResponse().getStatus();
            assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), status, "Incorrect Response Status");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private HttpHeaders buildClientHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("client_id", clientId);
        headers.add("client_secret", clientSecret);
        return headers;
    }
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute name must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest.setAttribute(MockHttpServletRequest.java:762)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:257)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:257)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)